# Yield return and "not all code paths return value"

Tags: c#, yield-return

Why the following code:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> TestYield(bool check)
{
    if (check)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the else");
    }
}
```

produces an error with "not all code paths return value".
However, the following code does not produce the same error:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> TestYield(bool check)
{
    if (check)
    {
        yield return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the else");
    }
}
```

The only difference is the yield. What yield is making different that does not cause the same error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use just return, because of your else statement does not return any thing, it gives you the error you mention and because you return int type it also gives the error "can not convert expression type int to return type IEnumerable".

When you use yield return, under the covers the yield keyword creates a state machine to maintain state information. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) : "When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called."

Now for your question "what happens in the else side" I took a look generated IL code with ILSpy. I created a class named YTest and added method which returns with yield. Here is the generated code :

```
internal class YTest
{
    [IteratorStateMachine(typeof(YTest.<TestYield>d__0))]
    public static IEnumerable<int> TestYield(bool check)
    {
        int num;
        while (num == 0)
        {
            if (!check)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In the else");
                IL_52:
                yield break;
            }
            yield return 1;
        }
        if (num != 1)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        goto IL_52;
    }
}
```

Compiler adds `yield break` statement under the hood.

When working with the yield keyword, you should keep these points in
   mind (besides msdn, quotes from https://www.infoworld.com/article/3122592/application-development/my-two-cents-on-the-yield-keyword-in-c.html

):

> - You cannot have the yield return statement in a try-catch block    though you can have it inside a try-finally block
> - You cannot have the yield break statement inside a finally block
> - The return type of the method where yield has been used, should be    IEnumerable, IEnumerable, IEnumerator, or IEnumerator
> - You cannot have a ref or out parameter in your method in which yield    has been used
> - You cannot use the "yield return" or the "yield break" statements    inside anonymous methods
> - You cannot use the "yield return" or the "yield break" statements    inside "unsafe" methods, i.e., methods that are marked with the
>     "unsafe" keyword to denote an unsafe context

Comment: Thx. But your answer says "When a yield return statement is reached..." , that's the point of my question here, the yield statement will not be reached if check = false .

Comment: You want some "code escapes" in here, the angle brackets disappeared

Comment: @isaac.hazan I updated my answer and add the generated IL code.

Comment: If you're going to quote directly from an article, as you have from https://www.infoworld.com/article/3122592/application-development/my-two-cents-on-the-yield-keyword-in-c.html, you should acknowledge that source.

Answer (score 13):

Any method body containing a `yield break` or a `yield return` statement is an *iterator block*. Within an iterator block, it's acceptable for execution to reach the closing brace of the method, as that's just equivalent to having a `yield break` - it's the end of the sequence.

In a regular method with a non-`void` return type, it's an error for the closing brace of a statement to be reachable. (Additionally, `return 1;` isn't a valid statement in a regular method with a return type of `IEnumerable<int>`.)

Comment: return 1 is a valid statement. For example the following functions runs totally fine.
     private static IEnumerable<int> YieldSubCall()
        {
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
            yield return 3;
            yield return 4;
            yield return 5;
        }

Comment: Not sure i am clear about your answer. Let's say check = false in the above. What the iterator will contain? Is there like a hidden "return null" here?

Comment: @isaac.hazan It will contain an empty sequence of ints. The sequence object will not be null, but it will not contain any ints. An iterator block always returns a non-null sequence, `yield return`s only define what goes into it. Thus `yield return` is different from `return`, and `return 1` is not valid in a method returning `IEnumerable<int>` like Jon Skeet said.

Comment: @GSerg : so the else will be done but an empty sequence will be returned?

Comment: @isaac.hazan: That's `yield return 1;` not `return 1;`. They're entirely different. Your first method is not an iterator block, and there is no conversion from `int` to `IEnumerable<int>`, so that would be an error: `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'`. (You should see that already.)

Comment: @isaac.hazan: And yes, if an iterator block reaches the end of the method without hitting a `yield return` statement, the returned sequence will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code you are returning only 1 which is a single integer value but the return type of the method is

```
IEnumerable<int>
```

as per Microsoft; they clearly said that you should use

```
 yield return statement to return each element one at a time.
```

You consume an iterator method by using a foreach statement or **LINQ** query. So basically, if you do not want to iterate then no need to use yield and IEnumerable but if you really want to iterate through your data or file then you should use **yield**.

Please read [Yield by MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) for more information.